# How can Create MDI Forms

Tags: windows

I am using C#
I want code to Create MDI Child Forms. I want to Open a child class from Main Form Menu Item.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xyhh2e7e.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You simply need to set the `MdiParent` property of the child form.

```
MyChildForm child = new MyChildForm();
child.MdiParent = this;//where 'this' refers to your main form
child.Show();
```

And you also need to have set `IsMDIContainer = true` for your main form.

There is a [walkthrough of the basics on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xyhh2e7e.aspx).